# How to get "page","pages","start","end","length" details using angular datatables

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Trying to get "page","pages","start","end","length" details and tried below code but not getting the results. If we click on next or prev buttons of respective page, start record and end records required. Plese help me.

```
table = $('#firstTable').DataTable();
info = this.table.page.info(); 
console.log(info.page +' of '+ info.pages);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/page-information)

Comment: Remove `this` from `this.table`
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/page-information-zaxwfe?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get if pagination numbers/buttons click (next prev first last) also getting the data ? please suggest me...

Comment: @Rajasekhar inside dtOption object  `drawCallback: function(s) {
        console.log('draw');
        $('.paginate_button.next').on('click', () => {
          console.log('next-button-click');
        });
        $('.paginate_button.previous').on('click', () => {
          console.log('previous-button-click');
        });
      }, ` here is https://stackblitz.com/edit/page-information-c5vxk5 link